# What is the angle between the lines joining two adjacent vertices of a cube to the centre of the cube?

Tags: geometry

I calculated that the length of any line joining the vertex of a cube with side 2 to its centre is $\sqrt{3}$. Then I used the cosine formula to obtain:

EDIT:

$$\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{(\sqrt{3})^2 + (\sqrt{3})^2 - 2^2}{2 (\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3})}$$

$$\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{2}{6} = \dfrac{1}{3} $$

Is this correct please?

Comment: Yes, this seems correct to me, or at least in the right ballpark (hard to parse your math notation). See [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry/gen-chem-review/hybrid-orbitals-jay/v/tetrahedral-bond-angle-proof) and [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22space+diagonals%22+angle+%22law+of+cosines%22).

Comment: Yes. Suppose the cube's center is at $C=(0,0,0)$ and the vertices are the 8 points $(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1).$  The distance from  $C$ to any vertex is $\sqrt {(\pm 1)^2+(\pm 1)^2+(\pm 1)^2}$ $=\sqrt 3,$  and the distance between adjacent vertices $V,V'$ is $2$. So, as you did,  the cosine formula gives an angle $VCV'= \cos^{-1}(1/3).$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.

In order to confirm your computation using a different method, you can use

$$\langle v,w\rangle=\lVert v\rVert\cdot\lVert w\rVert\cdot\cos\angle(v,w)$$

So the value of the dot product (inner product) is equal to the product of the lengths times the cosine of the angle. Which gives you another way to solve for the cosine of the angle and confirm your computation.

Using the vectors $v=(1,1,1)$ and $w=(1,1,-1)$ you get

$$\cos\theta=
\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\lVert v\rVert\cdot\lVert w\rVert}=
\frac{1+1-1}{\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt3}=
\frac13\\
\theta\approx70.528779365509308630754°$$

If you want yet another confirmation, look this sequence of digits up in OEIS and you will find [A137915](http://oeis.org/A137915) in degrees or [A137914](http://oeis.org/A137914) in radians. The latter writes

> Arccos(1/3) is the central angle of a cube, made by the center and two neighboring vertices. - [Clark Kimberling](http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Clark_Kimberling), Feb 10 2009